# How to add custom style to a word document?

Tags: macos, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-2016

How to add a custom style to a word document using the word javascript API. I tried adding the styles by insertOoxml. It is not working. I want some of my custom styles to be available for use in the word javascript API so that I can change style of documents via my add-in. Also, is it possible to create new styles programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported but its a capability that we definitely will add in the future.
You can use a custom style if already present in the document, you just do range.font.style = "Name of the style".

Comment: Has there been any movement on this issue?  IMO, this is a significant limitation of the current API.